# Is there a way to use a tolower() like function on a vector<string> variable in C++?

Tags: c++, string, file, vector, c++17

I'm trying to load and sort a file alphabetically. To make this easier, I have to convert the characters to lowercase.

Now, do I have to do this character-by-character as I read it into a string array (because `tolower()` only accepts characters), or can I somehow use it with a `vector<string>` container?

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   ifstream file("phoneNumbers.txt");
   vector<string> wordStream;
   int i = 0;

    if (file.fail()) {
        cout << "Couldn't open file!";
        return 1;
    }

    while(file>>wordStream[i]) {
        wordStream[i] = tolower(wordStream[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Newbie question, I know.

I already tried the `std::transform()` function that someone recommended on StackOverflow, but still it didn't work.

Comment: Nothing wrong with doing it one character at a time, if you can make it work that way. `std::transform` would work as well though.

Comment: Your code has a completely different problem, your vector has size zero. so `wordStream[i]` is an out of bound vectors access. Use `push_back` to add strings to the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two problems, `tolower` doesn't work on strings, and your vector has a size of zero so `wordStream[i]` is an error for any value of `i`. Here's the code fixed of those errors

```
string temp;
while (file >> temp) { // read to a temporary string
    // convert string to lower case
    std::transform(temp.begin(), temp.end(), temp.begin(), tolower);
    // add temporary string to vector
    wordStream.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: Side note: `tolower`'s parameter is an `int`, not a `char`, so that it can handle out of band codes. This can lead to [interesting problems with a simple resolution outlined here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower#Notes).

Comment: Passing `tolower` may also fail depending on the implementation, especially with OP's `using namespace std;` because there is another overload in the standard library. The only reliable way is to pass `[](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); }` (with or without `std::` if using `using namespace std;`) or equivalent.

Comment: Note that since C++20 taking the address of `std::tolower` (passing it as a function parameter) is Unspecified Behaviour - [Addressing restriction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction).  Using a lambda wrapper is the simplest way to avoid this.  _"...The behavior of a C++ program is unspecified ... if it explicitly or implicitly attempts to form a pointer, reference ... or pointer-to-member ... to a standard library function or an instantiation of a standard library function template, unless it is designated an addressable function ..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten Interesting, another reason to use a lambda here. I was aware of the int parameter issue but not this. I'm curious though, what's the reasoning behind this change? Seems quite a big deal to me.

Comment: @john This Reddit thread contains references to the papers addressing the issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/hewx2o/why_cant_i_take_an_address_of_a_standard_library/ .  Looks to be a way to future proof use of the Standard Library if any of the function signatures change.